# Android app running on emulator Sync to app on localhost?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am implementing C2DM (possibly not relevant) in an android app testing on an emulator. I have just got the C2DM registration working with the C2DM service so now I need to register my app with my web app,

As my web app is in dev mode (Rails METAL server) it is running on http://localhost:3020

I need to know if this is reachable from the emulator as I'm not getting anything through to the web app when the registration ID is received in response to the Google C2DM registration process by the andropid app and I'm struggling to work out if I have an issue with my code or if this is because localhost is not reachable.

Thanks in advance for any information on this

**UPDATE**
I found out from http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses that 10.0.2.2 will route to 127.0.0.1 but not sure how that would help me get to http://localhost:3020

I'm using a global variable for this

`public static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";`

Any ideas what I should set this to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3020";` as 10.0.2.2 is going to be "your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on *your development machine*)" as per the link you posted.

Comment: @Phillipp Reichart I think this will work, I have discovered that my code was not being called so I will test this solution as soon as I have my code sorted. Thanks very much for the response

Comment: Finally managed to get my code working and your answer is exactly what I needed. thank you very much!